# PowerApps - what could be licensing requirement for me to create entities in CDS?

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, common-data-service

I exported a SharePoint list to Excel and then tried Data -> Entities -> Get Data to create entities in CDS uploading data from Excel. It says 'You are missing privileges to create entities in this environment.' What could I do?

Comment: did you try google/internet with that error message? Did you try anything to solve using existing answers in other forums?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibilities of this error while creating entity are:

1. You are trying to create entity in some environment where you don't have security role/privilege to do this operation, viz Environment Admin, System Admin, System Customizer or custom Admin role
2. Trying this operation in Default or a CDS environment without database provisioning (highly unlikely)
3. Probably you have Environment maker role, client assumes that it is enough which is not the case

Try to get Admin privileges in Dev/sandbox environment from your client or create a trial org to try out things. You may have license but the basic role to access the system as an end user will not help you to do such stuffs.

Comment: thanks. environment is company_name (default) ( upgrade) on top right corner

Comment: @RajuChoudhari do you see anything else? Checked with client?

Comment: not sure where else could i see what license do I currently have? which one do I need? I checked your other posts on this site and find them informative but I am still not clear on this 2 questions. I am able to open admin console but there is no environment and does not let me create one either it seems

Comment: tried checking with client, says enterprise IT admins are mostly beyond our reach and for most part we need figure this out on our own

Comment: one suggestion I got is to request P1 license that could help me create entities in CDS?

Comment: @RajuChoudhari  still you should ask someone who is Sys admin to assign you higher privileged security role. Your Dev team or support team?

Comment: I agree and I am trying to request P1 license with as CDS -Environment maker role in Dev. I could update you on how this goes